# Javafx how to add everytime new element to the same row in new column tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I have TableView and my purpose is to have just one row at all [not included the col's title for each col]. And in every cell in the first row. I'll have ProgressIndicator.

Now, my purpose is everytime someone presses 'Add' it'll go to the OnAddButtonPressed function action and will add new col and in the first row in this specific col was just added a new progressIndicator will be added.

In my code right now, what is happening is everytime someone presses on 'ADD' what happens is all the ProgressIndicator were from earlier are moving to the new col and the num of rows gets incremented and all of the ProgressIndicator from the earalier columns gets removed and being "pushed" one by one to the new col.

```
@FXML
private void OnAddButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
    int currentCPUTimeRequestedInteger;
    String currentCPUTimeRequested = this.addTextField.getText();
    if(currentCPUTimeRequested.isEmpty() || currentCPUTimeRequested.length() > 1 ||     !Character.isDigit(currentCPUTimeRequested.toCharArray()[0]) || currentCPUTimeRequested.toCharArray()[0] ==     '0')
    {
        PopAddButtonError();
        return;
    }
    if(m_NumOfCols == MAX_NUM_OF_COLS - 1)
    {
        this.addButton.setDisable(true);
        this.addTextField.setDisable(true);
        this.enterCPUTimeLabel.setDisable(true);
    }
    if(firstTimePressedAdd == false)
    {
        this.firstTimePressedAdd = true;
        this.startButton.setDisable(false);
        this.listOfProcesses = new LinkedList<Process>();
    }
    currentCPUTimeRequestedInteger = Integer.parseInt(currentCPUTimeRequested);
    this.addTextField.setText("");
    AddNewColToTable(currentCPUTimeRequestedInteger);
}

private void AddNewColToTable(int CPUTimeRequested)
{
    Process newProcess = new Process(CPUTimeRequested);
    this.listOfProcesses.add(newProcess);
    TableColumn newCol = new TableColumn("P" + newProcess.GetId());
    newCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Process, String>("progressIndicator"));
    ObservableList<Process> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    data.add(newProcess);
    this.tableOfProcesses.getColumns().add(newCol);
    this.tableOfProcesses.getItems().addAll(data);
    this.tableOfProcesses.refresh();
    this.m_NumOfCols++;
}
```

My purpose is to have it the next way like in this photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC5cl.jpg)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tables are simply not designed to do this in JavaFX. Maybe a `ListView` in a horizontal orientation with an appropriate custom list cell would work. At any rate, you should create and post a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You *could* do this with a TableView but it's about 10 times more difficult than it has to be.  It's trivial to create the display in your image with an `HBox` filled with `Labels`.  Put each `ProgressIndicator` in the `Label` using `setGraphic()`, and the title via `setText()`.  Set the orientation so the title is on the top.    
QED

Comment: I agree with @James_D [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411803/javafx-how-to-add-everytime-new-element-to-the-same-row-in-new-column-tableview#comment133062364_75411803) that `TableView` is not appropriate for what you are trying to do. I suggest [HBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411803/javafx-how-to-add-everytime-new-element-to-the-same-row-in-new-column-tableview#comment133062364_75411803) or `TilePane` or `GridPane`. In other words, add your `ProgressBar`s to one of those, rather than to a `TableView`.

Answer (score 2):

Treating this as an XY problem.

Here's how the sample image can mostly be achieved via an HBox:

```
class Progresses : Application() {
   private var counter: Int = 0

   override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
      primaryStage.scene = Scene(createContent())
      primaryStage.show()
   }

   private fun createContent(): Region = BorderPane().apply {
      val hBox = HBox(20.0)
      bottom = createButton(hBox)
      center = hBox
      padding = Insets(20.0)
      minWidth = 400.0
      minHeight = 150.0
   }

   private fun createButton(targetPane: Pane) = buttonOf("New Progress") { buttonAction(targetPane) }

   private fun buttonAction(targetPane: Pane) {
      targetPane.children += Label("P${counter++}").apply {
         contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.BOTTOM
         graphic = ProgressIndicator().apply {
            progress = -1.0
            object : AnimationTimer() {
               var count = 0
               override fun handle(now: Long) {
                  progress = (count++ / 5000.0).toDouble()
               }
            }.start()
         }
      } 
   }
}

fun main() = Application.launch(Progresses::class.java)
```

It's Kotlin, but you should be able to figure it out.  It looks like this:

[image]

If the column heading styling is really required, you can style the Labels to give the same look and feel, or divide it into a VBox if that makes it easier.

Comment: Is this pure `JavaFX`? I think `JavaFX` answer should be written in `JavaFX`.

Comment: That is pure, unadulterated JavaFX.

Comment: It is JavaFX coded in Kotlin, as long as the original poster understands what portions apply to their situation, I think it's fine.

Comment: It probably okay. I just imagine a `Java/JavaFX` beginner running into an issue understanding the answer because it is written in `Kotlin`.

Comment: @SedJ601 I think that Kotlin code is generally simple to get the gist of if you know Java.  It's probably not too hard to grok out `BorderPane().apply{}`, especially if you recognize that `bottom`, `center`, `padding` and so on are configuration elements of `BorderPane`.   
  
In many ways, I think that Kotlin is easier to understand as answer code than Java for JavaFX, because it's just so much cleaner.  That code in my answer is a complete, runnable example in about 25 lines.  And it goes above and beyond because it actually has `ProgressIndicators` that do something.

Comment: As I said above, I have people in mind that are just learning `Java/JavaFX`. `Kotlin` may be less code, but for a new `Java` programmer, it's going to be more complicated to understand. I have been programming for over 10 years (Java for 7), and I am not a fan of `Kotlin` and find it harder to read.

Comment: @SedJ601 what don't you like about Kotlin?

Comment: I don't care for it because the programming style is different from conventional programming styles. It's the same reason I don't care for `Closure`. I started with `C++`, and it took me zero time to learn `Java` and `C#`. I can't say the same for `Closure` or `Kotlin`.